# Why I can iterate on array in forEach loop in Java?

Tags: java, iterator

It is common idea that I cannot iterate on some structure with forEach if this structure isn't Iterable. But why I can iterate on array in Java? Array isn't `Iterable`.

```
MyClass[] array = {new MyClass("a"), new MyClass("b")};

for (MyClass c : array) {
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Comment: You can iterate over an array because the ranged-for construct works on both Iterables _and_ Arrays. The compiler generates one style of bytecode if the argument is an Iterable, and another if it's an Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `For-Each` Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) says in part *The for-each construct is also applicable to arrays*.

The [JLS-14.4.2 The enhanced `for` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) says (in part),

> The type of the Expression must be `Iterable` or an array type

Answer (score 9):

The reason is that the [language has made an allowance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) for it.  While it may represent the two objects differently, the sequence of iteration is the same - and the effect is transparent to you.

> ...Otherwise, the Expression necessarily has an array type, `T[]`.
>
> Let L<sub>1</sub> ... L<sub>m</sub> be the (possibly empty) sequence of labels immediately
>   preceding the enhanced for statement.
>
> The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of
>   the form:
>
> ```
> T[] #a = Expression;
> L1: L2: ... Lm:
> for (int #i = 0; #i < #a.length; #i++) {
>     VariableModifiersopt TargetType Identifier = #a[#i];
>     Statement
> }
> ```
>
> `#a` and `#i` are automatically generated identifiers that are
>   distinct from any other identifiers (automatically generated or
>   otherwise) that are in scope at the point where the enhanced for
>   statement occurs.
>
> TargetType is the type of the loop variable as denoted by the Type
>   that appears in the FormalParameter followed by any bracket pairs that
>   follow the Identifier in the FormalParameter (§10.2).

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because Java has a built in way of handling arrays in a for each loop.  Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)